# Dynamic SQL Query for Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need some help in creating a stored procedure or a dynamic SQL query to query a matrix and have a output in a required format.

- Database: SQL Server 2014
- States table - screenshot:

[image]

Required output

[image]

More states will added to the table. So the Script should be able to dynamically get all the rows and columns.

The output is to create a new table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: search `unpivot dynamic sql`

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below links for your reference it may help you for logic

[How to pivot table in SQL Server with a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360838/how-to-pivot-table-in-sql-server-with-a-stored-procedure/41361247#41361247)

[Dynamic Pivot Queries with dynamic dates as column header in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712081/dynamic-pivot-queries-with-dynamic-dates-as-column-header-in-sql-server/41712560#41712560)

Note: The above links for pivoting.better refer it and do the unipovt